# No of pairs having both values greater than x and y respectively

Tags: c++, std-pair

We are given a `std::vector` of `n` pairs. (0 < n < 10^5). We are given `q` queries (0 < q <10^5). for each query we are given two numbers `X` and `Y`, we have to tell no of pairs which has first value greater than `X` and second value greater than `Y`.

I tried naive solution for this problem by search linearly for every query. But How can i do this in optimized way?

e.g.

```
16 11 10 20 18
11 9  2  2  4

(16,11) is the first pair, (11,9) is the second, then (10,2) .....so on

queries: 5
3 20 
4 5 
9 1 
4 6
8 4

output - 0 2 5 2 2
```

Comment: If there is no rule governing the order in which the elements occur then O(N) is the best you can do.

Comment: Please add the code you tried and also explain what you want to optimize for.

Comment: 2 collections, one sorted by x, the other sorted by y might help...

Comment: @Jarod42 we need to consider pair as a whole, I mean first value of pair should be greater than x and second should be greater than y.

Comment: I understand, but one dimension can be handled in `O(log(n))`, and the linear part for the other dimension is reduced (I don't know if it is enough).

Comment: @MeenuMeena A simple solution would be to first sort the vector based on say first element of the pair. For each query get X and try a modified binary search to find closest to x in the vector then you need to linearly loop through a far smaller set just checking for y

Comment: Are the queries online or offline?

Comment: @fedemengo offline

Comment: Well actually it doesn't even matter, you can simply perform two binary search for each query to get the number of values larger than `X` and `Y` let's say it's `x` and `y` and the answer will be `min(x, y)`. There are `3` pairs with first number larger than `3` and  `0` pairs with the second number larger than `20` you answer is `0` and so on. Total complexity is `q*log(n)`

Comment: @fedemengo No you can not do that. Thats what i am saying you have to take pair as a whole. Now according to you lets take a  query X=19, Y=10. so there is one pair having first value greater than 19 ( 20,2) and there is one pair having second value greater than 10 (16,11) . so according to you answer will be 1 but lets look at the example there is no pair having x>19 and y>10.

Comment: @fedemengo PS 'There are 3 pairs with first number larger than 3' NO,  all the pairs have x>3. i.e all the 5 pairs.

Comment: You should just post the link to the competitive coding site this question is coming from. And your code as well. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Your question, without code, is vague. The first comment also answers your questions unless you can provide details that might allow for a more efficient solution.

Comment: You've asked questions before, but never gave feed-back to the answers posted, nor marked an answer as accepted. I don't think you'll find a lot of enthusiasm for your questions now.

Comment: Suggest you look into quadtrees or B-trees.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my take on the problem using [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

This took me **a lot of work**, so probably I should have spent my time for more useful activities...

In short, I define a `kdtree` which has `pair` (the data type for the point) and `node` the classical binary tree node. The trick is that the tree is sorted on `x` at the root, then on `y` at its children, then again on `x` at the next level, then on `y`, and so on.

It's important to have a balanced tree, so I use `std::nth_element()` to find the median at each step.

A lot of work was spent for the testing program, which required me to check **again** how to measure time in C++, and how to generate random numbers... sigh.

In the end I compare the timing with linear search and the proposal of Jaysmito Mukherjee (sort on `x`, binary search, then linear from that point on). **With these queries**, where x,y ∈ [500,1000], meaning that at most 1/16ᵗʰ of the space is queried, I got (only one run):

```
Linear search: 21.3098s
kd-tree: 0.867722s
OK: results_linear == results_kdtree
Binary search: 2.01137s
OK: results_linear == results_binary
```

At the beginning I used the same distribution (range [-1000,1000]) for both data and queries and the timing was awful! Then I realized that the queries were returning most of the vector every time. So, everything depends on the selectivity of your query.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct kdtree {
    struct pair {
        int x, y;
    };
    struct node {
        pair p_;
        node* left_ = nullptr;
        node* right_ = nullptr;
        node(const pair& p) : p_(p) {}
    };

    node* root_;

    void insert(node*& n, std::vector<pair>& v, size_t start, size_t stop, size_t depth) 
    {
        if (stop <= start) {
            return;
        }

        size_t mid = (start + stop) / 2;
        std::nth_element(v.begin() + start, v.begin() + mid, v.begin() + stop,
            [&](const pair& a, const pair& b) { 
                return depth % 2 ? a.y < b.y : a.x < b.x;
            });
        n = new node(v[mid]);
        insert(n->left_, v, start, mid, depth + 1);
        insert(n->right_, v, mid + 1, stop, depth + 1);
    }

    kdtree(std::vector<pair> &v) 
    {
        insert(root_, v, 0, v.size(), 0);
    }

    void print_rec(const node* n, size_t tab = 0) {
        std::cout << std::string(tab, '\t');
        if (n) {
            std::cout << n->p_.x << ',' << n->p_.y << '\n';
            print_rec(n->left_, tab + 1);
            print_rec(n->right_, tab + 1);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "nil\n";
        }
    }
    void print() { print_rec(root_); }

    // Find all pairs with x>a && y>b
    size_t query_rec(const node* n, int a, int b, size_t depth)
    {
        size_t npairs = n->p_.x > a && n->p_.y > b;
        //if (npairs) {
        //  std::cout << n->p_.x << ',' << n->p_.y << '\n';
        //}

        if (n->left_) {
            auto lower = depth % 2 ? n->p_.y < b : n->p_.x < a;
            if (!lower) {
                npairs += query_rec(n->left_, a, b, depth + 1);
            }
        }
        if (n->right_) {
            npairs += query_rec(n->right_, a, b, depth + 1);
        }
        return npairs;
    }
    size_t query(int a, int b) {
        return query_rec(root_, a, b, 0);
    }
};

struct perf {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_;
    perf() : start_(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {}
    double elapsed() const {
        auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = stop - start_;
        return elapsed_seconds.count();
    }
};

int main()
{
    const size_t nelems = 100000;
    const size_t nqueries = 100000;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> data_dist(-1000, 1000);
    std::vector<kdtree::pair> v;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), nelems, [&]() { return kdtree::pair{ data_dist(mt), data_dist(mt) }; });

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> queries_dist(500, 1000);
    std::vector<kdtree::pair> queries;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(queries), nqueries, [&]() { return kdtree::pair{ queries_dist(mt), queries_dist(mt) }; });

    perf p1;
    std::vector<size_t> results_linear;
    results_linear.reserve(nqueries);
    for (const auto& q : queries) {
        results_linear.push_back(std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
            [&q](const kdtree::pair& p){ return p.x > q.x && p.y > q.y; })
        );
    }
    std::cout << "Linear search: " << p1.elapsed() << "s\n";

    perf p2;
    std::vector<size_t> results_kdtree;
    results_kdtree.reserve(nqueries);
    kdtree t(v);
    for (const auto& q : queries) {
        results_kdtree.push_back(t.query(q.x, q.y));
    }
    std::cout << "kd-tree: " << p2.elapsed() << "s\n";

    if (results_linear == results_kdtree) {
        std::cout << "OK: results_linear == results_kdtree\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "FAIL: results_linear != results_kdtree\n";
    }

    perf p3;
    std::vector<size_t> results_binary;
    results_binary.reserve(nqueries);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const kdtree::pair& a, const kdtree::pair& b) { return a.x < b.x; });
    for (const auto& q : queries) {
        auto it = std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), q, [](const kdtree::pair& a, const kdtree::pair& b) { return a.x < b.x; });
        results_binary.push_back(std::count_if(it, v.end(),
            [&q](const kdtree::pair& p) { return p.x > q.x && p.y > q.y; })
        );
    }
    std::cout << "Binary search: " << p3.elapsed() << "s\n";

    if (results_linear == results_binary) {
        std::cout << "OK: results_linear == results_binary\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "FAIL: results_linear != results_binary\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee Please check if I implemented what you were suggesting.

Comment: @MeenuMeena Check the edited answer,which adds also binary search. And accept it if it solves your problem.